# Customize WPF TabControl TabItem Header

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am using a TabControl as a makeshift wizard.  So I don't want the user clicking to the next tab. I am able to do it like this;

```
<TabControl Name="myTabControl" >
    <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed">
        <!-- XMAL stuff -->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed">
        <!-- XMAL stuff -->
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The issue being is there is a white border that appears;

[image]

How do I remove the white border?

thanks

edit:  Doing some more testing it appears the white border is not a border but the background of the TabControl.  I was able to fix it by doing this;

```
<TabControl Name="myTabControl" >
    <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid Margin="-2">
            <!-- XMAL stuff -->
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid Margin="-2">
            <!-- XMAL stuff -->
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Seems like a stupid way of fixing this

Comment: For wizard functionality, you can try to use Frame and put your XAML stuff in Pages. Frame Navigation (Next and Prev) function can be handle by `frame.NavigationService.GoBack();` or `frame.NavigationService.GoForward();`

Comment: *Seems like a stupid way of fixing this*... perhaps it was, but if you showed us some code that *actually* reproduced your problem, then maybe someone could have shown you a less *stupid* way to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to set the tabitem's template(it is actually tabitem header's template) to empty:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

Also, try to set border thickness to zero:

```
<TabControl BorderThickness="0">
```

Comment: Both of those do nothing.  It seems the white border is not a border but the actual background of the TabControl

Comment: Both at the same time and still no result?

Comment: Works for me, Eugene.